# In DFP, how do I make the placements sticky or floating?

Tags: google-dfp

If someone gives me a third party tag, is there a setting - regardless of the tag itself - within DFP itself that can turn this tag into floating or sticky?

Floating means a smaller sized version of the ad will follow you on the corner of the screen, if the user scrolls up or down form the original ad.

Sticky means an ad that remains still on the side of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Google has added a new template "Mobile Adhesion" in DFP recently. It is a mobile format (image only currently) that sticks at the bottom (but the user have the option to close the banner).
In fact, the format can be used in a similar manner on desktop, you just need to put the appropriate image (size).
If you want a sticky format that form example is situated in the sidebar, but scrolls (stays sticky) with content, you need to code it yourself, based on the structure of your website.

Comment: Sadly I need video-only...I didn't understand the phrase "a sticky format that form example is situated". Do you mean to do it outside of DFP and then plant the DFP code inside it?

Comment: Yes, it should be outside of DFP and the DFP code should be the floating element.